# jQuery: Append <audio> with autoplay: File played twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html5-audio

I need to append audio players on click. They should autoplay since that saves an annoying extra click.

Now the problem is that appending the audio player starts the sound file twice (at least in Chrome).

HTML:

```
<a id="link" href="javascript:void(0)">Click to toggle player</a>
```

JS:

```
var url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Butterfield_All_These_Blues.ogg',
    audio = '<p><audio controls autoplay src="'+url+'"></audio></p>';

$("#link").click(function() {
    $(this).after( audio + '<p>Now pause the audio. A second file plays in the off.</p>');
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/ddLzvj9r/

Comment: silver lining, click toggle several times and you get a wicked echo effect

Comment: I removed autoplay now and `trigger('play')` on click: http://jsfiddle.net/ddLzvj9r/2/